# DynamoDB (dynamoose) - TypeError: model.save is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm using dynamoose to access DynamoDB from node.js

I'm implementing a CRUD API in node.js with swagger and having difficulties with the UPDATE (put) endoint. It should be very similar to the POST endpoint, which by the way is working fine.

I've defined a dynamoose Schema and exported a dynamoose Model based on that Schema.

Then, I've implemented a controller module that imports the model and uses the dynamoose API model functions to work with the database. This fragment of code shows how the post method is implemented in the controller:

```
'use strict';

// my-model.js exports the model
var MyModel = require('../models/my-model');

var MyController = {

       postMyObject: function(req, res) {

                var myModel = new MyModel();

                myModel.attr1 = req.body.attr1; // primary key
                myModel.attr2 = req.body.attr2;

                myModel.save(function(err, myModelStored) {
                        if (err) {
                                console.log("Error storing InvoiceConfig");

                                res.status(500).send({message: `${err}`});
                        }

                        res.status(200).send(myModelStored);
                });
       }
}

module.exports = MyController;
```

As you can see, inside the post method of the controller, a model is instantiated, the properties are set from the parameter received in the body of the POST request and finally the [model.save](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#modelputoptions-callback--modelsaveoptions-callback) method is called to store the model in the database. This works.

Now, I want to add an update method to my controller, to update the properties of one of the items stored in the database. According to the dynAmoose API documentation, [model.save & model.put](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#modelputoptions-callback--modelsaveoptions-callback) "put the the item in the DynamoDB table and overwrite the item". That means I can use it for my update method, I pass the whole object (including the updated properties) and it will overwrite the object with the specified primary key.

According to that, I implement the update method in my controller:

```
'use strict';

// my-model.js exports the model
var MyModel = require('../models/my-model');

var MyController = {

       updateMyObject: function(req, res) {

                var myModel = new MyModel();

                myModel.attr1 = req.swagger.params.id.value;  // Primary key
                myModel.attr2 = req.body.attr2;

                // Overwrites the object in the DB
                myModel.save(function(err, myModelUpdated) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Error in update method");
                            res.status(500).send({message: `${err}`});
                        }

                        res.status(200).send(myModelUpdated);
                });
       },

       postMyObject: function(req, res) {

                var myModel = new MyModel();

                myModel.attr1 = req.body.attr1; // primary key
                myModel.attr2 = req.body.attr2;

                myModel.save(function(err, myModelStored) {
                        if (err) {
                                console.log("Error in post method");
                                res.status(500).send({message: `${err}`});
                        }

                        res.status(200).send(myModelStored);
                });
       }
}

module.exports = MyController;
```

But when I try to send a PUT (UPDATE) request of one of the items in the database, I get the following error in the update method of the controller:

```
TypeError: myModel.save is not a function
    at updateMyObject (/home/user/my-server/api/controllers/my-controller.js:15:17)
```

As you can see, the updateMyObject method of MyController is almost identical to the postMyObject method, only that the update method receives the primary key parameter in the path.

Why does it complain about the model.save dynamoose API function being not found in the updateMyObject method when it works fine in postMyObject?

Edit:
The dynamoose module is imported in ../models/my-model.js:

```
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
```

Comment: Just edited my question to remark that the dynamoose module is accesible from the controller (required by my-model.js itself)

Comment: Are you using Express or Hapi REST api ?

Comment: @notionquest I'm using express